# Scraping fast changing values in a microchip generated webpage (Webserver) in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, iot

I have never done website scraping before. Not even sure if this is the way to go.
I want to be able to collect data from the tables in the image, which changes 5 times in a second for every parameter. This data will be available on this webserver (IP accessible) created automatically by a microchip. I want to collect and save this data to a database quick enough.
Am I correct to be looking into beautiful soup/selenium? If not, what tools can I use to collect and store data and make sure it is updated every second?
Any help much appreciated!

PS: I only know Python and SQL.

[Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaDjl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Open Inspect Element and see if its a WS connection or simple AJAX

If its WS, then use https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/

If its AJAX, then copy that request as cURL and convert that to Python code using https://curl.trillworks.com/

PS: you do not need to use Selenium at all.

Comment: The request counter at the bottom keeps increasing. I can't get just one request to copy curl. What does that mean? More here:  https://imgur.com/PIn36Rl

Comment: @MayankDhami thats an XHR (AJAX) request, just do what I said above in my answer

Comment: I tried doing that with just one file, since you see in screenshot there are many many files.  With curl code, I was able to fetch the data with headers.
`response = requests.get('http://xx.0.0.xxx/status.xml', headers=headers, verify=False)` `print(response.text)`                                                                                             
Output:                                                               <ISU_LEFT_LEFT_K>0</ISU_LEFT_LEFT_K>
<ISU_LEFT_MIDLE_K>0</ISU_LEFT_MIDLE_K>
However not sure if continuous changing values will be captured with just this code?

Answer (score -1):

I advise you to check `curl`. Whatever the language you wanna use.
What you want to do is possible with Selenium though

With Selenium :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
s = Service('chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
url = ...
driver.get(url)
while True:
    element = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "nameOfElement")
    #or driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "nameOfElement") or id or w/e
    content = element[0].text
    time.sleep(1)
```

etc ...